# Naming a range based on another cell's value in google sheets that will update automatically and protecting that named range

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, named-ranges

I'm trying to come up with a method of preventing users editing certain cells in Google Sheets but still being able to edit certain others.

I'm trying to think of a way to do this using built in features such as using named ranges using a lookup function to inform protected ranges but of course very open to any suggestions using other methods.

A very basic example of the desired result could be:

| Name | Data | More Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | James can edit this row except for name | More data James can Edit |
| James | James can edit this row and any other row created that their name is in the "Name" column of | Even more data James can Edit |
| Martin | Martin can edit this row except for name | More data Martin can Edit |
| James | Martin can edit this row and any other row created that their name is in the "Name" column of | Even more data Martin can Edit |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can protect certain ranges to be a read/write per user. However you run into issues if a user tries to add a sheet or some other cavalier action. Having the ranges automatically protected based on a table would require google app scripts.

Comment: thanks, could you provide an example?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have any lying around. Lookup `methods` on a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object in Google App Scripts.